# Is there something between auditing and taking for credit?

Tags: united-states, coursework

Is there a system in place that is in between auditing a course and taking it for credit?

I have audited a course before and I didn't learn enough material to prepare for the actual course.

Comment: So your intent is to audit the course, then take it for credit? Seems like you should just take it and put the effort into passing it for real.

Comment: @JonCuster for those with disabilities this is impractical.  For many students it takes multiple tries which institutions don't allow.

Comment: Certain courses, such as organic chemistry, are known for taking several tries for various students. Have you approached the proper office for disability assistance? But, ultimately, if you _need_ that course, you need to put in the time to prepare for it.

Comment: @William If you have disabilities, you should work with the institution's disability office (hopefully it has one...) to get proper accommodations. Taking a course multiple times by auditing it the first time does not seem like an ideal approach to me, especially if you pay the same rate for auditing a class as taking it "for real."

Comment: It would help to specify region/country here, as in some places you can just retake exams until you pass with no penalty, so there the answer is just "take the course/exams until you pass". If not, you could look to your institution's retake policies, as some in the US will let you retake if you have a D or below multiple times and they will not penalize your GPA as they only report the final taken grade. Other institutions have no such leeway and will report every grade earned *and* include it in the GPA; that provides much less flexibility. But this is all very locale-dependent.

Comment: Now that you have indicated you are in the US, in the two institutions I was a student at in the US you were permitted to retake courses. Both versions would show up on your transcript, but only the most recent grade was counted in your GPA. Additionally, if you are in the US your institution almost definitely has a disability office, you should consult them about all of this, they will be much more helpful than anyone here can be.

Comment: How much you learn is more dependent on what effort you actually put in than on your formal registration status.  For instance, if you audit the course, attend all the classes, take notes, study and review the material, complete all the assignments on your own, and (if possible) meet with the instructor occasionally to ask questions and check your understanding, you should be able to learn just as much as if you were taking the course for credit.

Comment: @NateEldredge How much you learn is dependent on a lot of things, not least of which is the course structure and the quality of the instruction.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: Certainly.  I didn't mean that as an exhaustive list, and I was focusing on aspects that are the student's decision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depends on your institution, so you will have to ask someone there, a general answer is not possible.

My undergrad institution allowed for taking some courses (specifically, those not part of the specific requirements towards your degree) as pass/fail rather than graded, which meant if you scored at least a C you got credit and if you scored worse than a C you didn't, and the course wasn't included in your GPA.

However, auditing a course typically gives you the same access to course materials as taking it for credit; the opportunity to learn should be the same however course credit is assigned. Auditing is not typically a way to prepare for a course, but rather for self-enrichment and perhaps to learn material outside your area of expertise without being evaluated to test your interests.

---

edit: The OP has since indicated that their reason for auditing these classes was that they hoped to prepare ahead of taking the course for a grade, due to disability they experience. I would recommend consulting with the institution's disability office to get proper accommodations rather than using the audit or pass/fail system directly.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely fair to assume that this is an issue of personal motivation. Courses tend to come in a one-size-fits-all structure, which can put many students, especially those with disabilities, at a significant disadvantage. I would be more inclined to place the blame with the institution for not requiring courses to be structured with greater adaptability to a variety of student learning needs.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I'll edit that out. I wrote that before the student mentioned a disability; at the time, it seemed like they were blaming auditing the course (i.e., not having responsibility for a grade for the course) for not getting enough out of it. I agree with you that there may be other structural issues with the course(s) to blame, but those cannot be addressed by the difference between auditing and taking a course for credit, and the next step is still to consult the disability office.